# HTTP Web Server: IBM Notes Exception - Entry not found in index

Tags: lotus-domino

A new form I just added to a database while troubleshooting has a single editable text field, and a button with @Command([FileSave]) code.  That is all, no @DBLookups, no webquerysave agent, nothing but those two things (except computed text showing my common name to ensure I was logged in).

Using a browser (Firefox), the form is presented, and I can edit the text field, but when I click the button I get an error:

```
Error 404 

HTTP Web Server: IBM Notes Exception - Entry not found in index
```

this is the error shown in the log:

```
HTTP Web Server: IBM Notes Exception - Entry not found in index [/dev/testcore.nsf/mgs?OpenForm&Seq=1] CN=Matthew Smith/O=mydomain
```

We have restarted the server completely (if that helps), but still getting this error.    I do not understand how this could be happening.   Existing forms in this mature database save fine, but not this one new one.

Comment: I assume you are trying to help with your extensive edits; however, I believe it was unnecessary, that my original question was understandable.  Thoughts?

Comment: Try with  @Command([FileSave]); @Command([FileCloseWindow])

Comment: Tried that...same error.   We are thinking we are narrowing it down to something buggy with the indexer/index due to other clues we are getting, but that could be a dead end too

Comment: And if you try the same in a new database with only your test form?

Comment: thank you for engaging in this, we were unable to determime the cause, and ended up replacing the entire database with a new one (same design and documents, and that cleared this up.   Suspect it was some kind of data corruption that was cleaned up during the creation of the new database.   Very strange, and had a ticket submitted with HCL, but could not  wait for an answer.    New replica ID is not an issue for us.

Answer (score 0):

There's very little to go on here, but I suspect that your database either has no views or has no default view. One of the things that happens when you open a document (as opposed to a form) is that it needs to determine if there's a Form Formula that applies to that document. If there is no current view node in the URL, or if the view node is '/0/', it should look for the default view to check if there's a Form Formula defined for the view. If there's no view at all, or no default, I can see that generating an "Entry not found in index" error since no default view entry is found in the index of the design notes collection.

Comment: see my answer to D Bugger above.   Agreed we had little to go on also, have never seen such behavior in 30 years